# Calculating Error on a Hold-Out Set

Tags: cross-validation, error, k-means

I broke some data into a training and a hold out set. Then I clustered the training set with the k-means method. Now I want to calculate error using the holdout set. Do I just take the square the distance of each point in the holdout set from the closest centroid, and then sum the distances?

Comment: that is the formula for within-cluster sum of squares (WSS).  what exactly are you trying to do?  This is not a regression model -- it is not like a low WSS means valid clusters -- if k=n then WSS = 0.  There are other techniques you should be using if you are trying to assess the validity of a clustering.

Comment: I'm trying to use the holdout set productively. Not sure how.